# MySQL How to add a new multicolumn index to an innodb table without triggering a repair?

Tags: mysql, indexing, innodb, alter-table

I have an innodb table that contains 70 million records and already has several single column indexes. I want to add a new multicolumn index that would allow me to run queries on multiple columns. I don't mind limited downtime (less than a day) but I want to avoid a repair with keycache or any other issues that might cause the addition of the new index to take a few days or weeks.

With the table being innodb, can the new index be added fairly quickly using CREATE INDEX, or would I need to back up the table and recover it to a new table with the desired indexes already added as is recommended for MyISAM tables? Or is there another strategy that is better suited to innodb?

Comment: What is your mySql version? and if its 5.1 or above, are you using innodb plugin ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to hell.  I think you have two choices:

1. suffer the downtime.  Just to commiserate, I have a table with almost 400M rows..
2. create a new table.  Move your live app to that and then migrate your old data into it in batches.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing, moving the data in batches. It took over a week. Tons of fun. Thanks for the suggestions.